How to use an alternator motor as an electric braking mechanism
I am working on an automation device that needs to stop a bobbin of wire from spinning out of control, so the idea is to have the bobbin connected to an alternator, and then connect the alternator's rectified output to some load to absorb this energy, but I am not sure if it's best to connect the alternator to a fixed power source / voltage, or just use a braking resistor.


I think there are easier ways to do this. Apply pressure from a fixed shaft, for instance, or use a bicycle disc brake, or one of these. Unless you want to reclaim the kinetic energy of the rotating bobbin, there are many simpler options than using a generator for braking.

Check out dynamometers. Or a hydraulic pump with suitable control.

A magnetic brake is a good no-wear solution with braking force proportional to speed. I think they're used on many "spinner" exercise bikes.

What size of bobbin are we talking about?

@Jeroen3 it's a 25 lb bobbin, around 12" diameter

One charm of using an electrical machine for breaking is feed-back - of information on speed&position.

The kinetic energy of the load will be converted to electrical energy at the alternator.
As you have already mentioned resistors, it's apparent you're happy to dump it as heat rather than recover it as electrical energy.
How you dump it depends on how much energy there is to deal with per braking event (the pulse energy), how many braking events there are per unit time (the average power).
The pulse energy, assuming a stop time of perhaps a few seconds, needs to be absorbed in raising the temperature of the mass of the resistor. Wirewound resistors often have a pulse rating.
The average power needs to be dissipated to ambient, typically by air-cooling.
You don't need to rectify the output to DC, you can put a resistive load directly onto the alternator. It doesn't even matter if it's a 3-phase alternator and you use unbalanced phases, you will still get a braking effect. It's probably best to be able to switch in different value resistors for low or high braking. At low speed, you could even short the phases together for maximum braking, when all the heat will go into the alternator windings.

yes, there is a motor that is reeling the wire on the bobbin, but the bobbin is not driven directly by the motor, it is connected to the alternator which will ideally stop it from spinning out of control as we near the end of the cycle. I updated the post with this.

A magnetic brake is a good no-wear solution with braking force proportional to speed. I think they're used on many "spinner" exercise bikes but also on arrester devices.
See Head Rush Technologies promotional video on YouTube. (I never heard of them before now.)

That looks interesting, the only problem i see is that it's self-regulating and will lead to the same braking speed at any force, but as we speed up, we don't want the motor to have to fight more against the bobbin, if that makes sense, we just need to make sure the bobbin doesnt go out of control when slowing down and approaching the end of the cycle.

It sounds like you need to edit your question and write a proper user requirement for your application. :^)

Alternators aren’t really designed to work that way. They have a minimum RPM to be effective.
A better option is a magnetic brake.
There are several types of magnetic brakes: powder, eddy current and hysteresis. This explains in more detail: https://magnetmfg.com/magnetic-brake-systems-exploring-their-applications-and-benefits/

Simply driving a stalled low torque DC motor backwards to provide constant torque may be a better solution - constant current feed to the motor.
First improvement, measure the back EMF of the motor (if the motor is spinning at any significant percentage of its normal running speed)  and adjust the motor voltage  as the motor spins up with the bobbin to keep the torque constant.
Extra points for measuring/estimating how much line has wound off the bobbin and adjusting the torque to match the radius of the top layer of the line on the bobbin.

Alternators can act as generators for braking by converting kinetic energy into electrical energy, used in systems like regenerative braking. Energy can be dissipated as heat via resistors (dynamic braking) or stored. The braking force depends on the electrical load applied, allowing controlled deceleration.

Look to trains and golf carts for the answer. Both employ dynamic braking, which utilizes wire-wound resistors to dissipate heat.
Observe a train engine from above. You will notice large banks of fans. These fans are employed to cool the dynamic braking resistors.
Modern golf carts employ regenerative and dynamic braking systems. The first time you drive one, you may find yourself thrust against the steering wheel when you release the accelerator. The braking is controlled by how much you ease off the accelerator pedal. Lift the seat, and you will find the braking resistors.
